# Wiring 24v bulbs to plug into mains

Tags: wiring

I am trying to wire sets of around 10 24v incandescent bulbs and am hoping to be able to plug them directly into the mains. I am by no means an expert in this kind of thing, but I believe that wiring them all in series won't work, and that there is likely some specific way in which they will need to be wired to allow me to plug them in directly without the need of a transformer.

Can anyone shed some light on how I can do this, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome, new user! I don't mean to be rude or anything, but if you're not knowledgeable enough in electrical instalations or engineering, don't mess with the mains. It can kill you.

Comment: Thanks for the concern/warning :) I think I'm going to play it safe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can add the voltage ratings of all the bulbs connected in series, but *only if they are all the same type of bulb*.  Your string of ten 24 V bulbs will effectively make one 240 V bulb electrically with 10x the power rating of the individual bulbs.  Again though, these 10 bulbs must all be of the same type and rating.  For example, mixing 24 V 5 W bulbs with 24 V 10 W bulbs violates this rule.

As the safety-nannies on this list are sure to continue pointing out, 240 V is dangerous and not something you should be messing with if you have to ask such a basic question here.  You probably shouldn't be trying to do this.  In case you do, we'll get a [Darwin Award](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Awards) ready for you.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info...I think I'll stay away from the "messing with the mains" then and just play it safe.

Comment: This is exactly what your typical Christmas tree lights are - lots of low voltage bulbs in series adding up to a total of 240V (20x12V for example).

Answer (score 1):

Theres two sides to this, the theoretical side and the practical side.

In principle as long as the bulbs are identical you can connect bulbs in series to use them on a higher voltage. You don't say what the mains voltage is in your country, if it's 240V (or thereabouts) then 10 24V bulbs in series will work. If your mains is only 120V then you would need to make two series strings of 5 and then connect the bulbs in series. Traditionally this was how christmas lights were done (you can still get such lights but they are less common now)

In practice there are a few downsides to connecting bulbs in series.

1. insulation requirements. The insulation between electrical connections and anything that people can touch must be suitable for the highest voltage present.
2. If one bulb fails open circuit the whole string goes out. Christmas lights worked around this by building antifuses into the bulb bases but there were still reliability issues and you could get issues with cascading failures as the antifuses activated and increased the voltage across the remaining bulbs.
3. On systems with only a couple of bulbs in serries (e.g. a pair of halogen floodlights wired in series across 400V because no neutral was available) i've heard of problems with one bulb in the pair failing and the surge from the failure taking out the other